# Using .Matches with regex for a char in fluent

Tags: c#, .net, regex, fluentvalidation

I have a class called `Transaction` which contains a property named `source`

Within the `Transaction` class I have some validation using `FluentValidation`, I am currently trying to validate the source property using `regex` however I'm having an issue

```
    //source isnt required but when present must be 1 character 'X' or 'Y'
    RuleFor(transaction => transacion.source)
        .Matches("^(X|Y)?$")
        .When(Transaction => transaction.source != null);
```

I am getting:

> Error 1   `FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderInitial<MyUtility.Transaction,char?>`
>   does not contain a definition for 'Matches' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   `FluentValidation.DefaultValidatorExtensions.Matches<T>(FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,string>,
>   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex)` has some invalid arguments

I have just used this exact same code for a different property with no problems, although that was a string not a char.

Comment: Don't think that's your issue, but FYI `(X|Y)` is `[XY]` (quicker to search and possibly easier to read)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an extra dot `.` in your code between `Matches` and `("^(X|Y)?$")`.

```
.RuleFor(transaction => transaction.source)
    .Matches("^(X|Y)?$") // dot was here
    .When(transaction => transaction.source != null);
```

And as Robin pointed out, the regex is more readable in a `[XY]` format.

**EDIT**

I just reread your post and it says that the `source` property is a `char` so if you convert it to a `string` you won't get the error.

```
.RuleFor(transaction => transaction.source.HasValue ? transaction.source.ToString() : "")
    .Matches("^[XY]?$") // dot was here
    .When(transaction => transaction.source != null);
```

Comment: Yes I realised this after I posted however still getting the same error message without it

Comment: @juan-facorro How would the regex be written in te [XY] format?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Just edited the answer with the `[XY]` format.

Comment: @juan-facorro Unit tests are failing if source is null, which it may possibly be, as its a char it is failing when attempting to convert to string - Any suggestions?

Comment: @SelectDistinct The solution for that is pretty straight-forward. Just  test for `null` before calling `.ToString()` in the lambda expression for the `RuleFor` constructor: `.RuleFor(x => (x.source.HasValue ? x.source.ToString() : ""))`.